# File upload and save file info to database in silverlight

Tags: sql, database, silverlight, file-upload

I know that out there a lots of posts but i coudn't find a example on how i can uload a video to server and save fileinfo to sql database. I am looking for a silverlight example. Video size would be arround 100-200 Mb.

If someone can point in the right direction , i would apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split the file and upload by chunk.

The steps :

1. In a cancelable thread : [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) ;
2. Split your file by chunk : [FileStream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) (Just read chunk one by one) ;
3. Send the file chunk : [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with a upload ID ;
4. Wait until the chunk is sent : [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) ;
5. Run the next chunk (step 2).

At the end you can use a Hash like md5 to test if your file is not corrupted.

You can send many chunk in the same time with an order parameter and, in the server side, reorder the chunk.

**Note :** You can find a sample by reading the project [Silverlight File Uploader](http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Okay, I added a direction to my post.